# How to expire inactive sessions on Parse Server

Tags: session, parse-platform, parse-server

In a bid to try and make my Parse powered app more secure I would like to be able to expire sessions on the server side. Upon launching my App (or visiting the Web App) I will run a check to see if the Session Token is valid.

Where I am struggling is actually being able to monitor the activity of a `session`. Parse.com have [alluded to this capability](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/announcing-new-enhanced-sessions/), however it is impossible to find anything mentioned in their documentation on the subject.

Additionally moving to NodeChef has given me the option to 'Expire In Active Sessions' However, it is not mentioned anywhere how it actually functions or how you can interact with this through cloud or client side code.

[image: NodeChef App Settings]

I do have the option of setting the session expiry time, however this is a hard and fast rule - it will happily expire the session even if the user is active! Not a nice user experience.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can manage this?

Answer (score -1):

I used this solution: 
Create cron job (in Linux) or Schedule Task (in windows) with **Parse Code Function** that will delete your expired token (With your costume logic)

Comment: what you mean by 'detele your expired token'? Could you share example code? If token is delete is deleted,this mean session is over and you wanted to extended it (I also need this)